# Optimal method to drive a pair of 10W 28V 0.35A LEDs using PWM for dimming

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, pwm, boost, led-driver

Using DC/DC boost converter is inevitable because the power supply will be 12V, so the voltage has to be stepped up to at least 28-30 volts. 
The biggest aspect I am looking at is to have as few components as possible. Using just a single driver IC without any PWM external generation circuit would be an advantage. The chip would have to have PWM generation inside itself. I am trying not to use any microcontroller for PWM generation, but 555 timer or other IC wouldn't be too bad, however, as I've mentioned before, the goal is use a single IC chip. So the key question is what would be the recommended IC for this specific LED drive.

Comment: There are hundreds of LED constant current boost voltage designs and commercial buy solutions.

Comment: Define ***optimal***. Area? Cost? Part count? Boutique? Efficient? Calibratable? Repeatable from build to build in terms of how it functions, for whatever calibration you are willing to accept? Etc.

Comment: Why **not** a microcontroller? There are many small package controllers that require very minimal external components with internal oscillator (no crystal) and internal flash and RAM. Just controller and decoupling caps. Certainly fewer components than a 555 oscillator and a lot more flexibility.

Comment: What I meant by saying optimal is having small part count for a reasonable price.

Comment: Also, if then I had to choose a small microcontroller for this scenario, which would it be? Also, can anybody recommend any LED driving chip for my particular LED specifications?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist out of those "hundreds", how many will work with 12V in and 30V out?

Comment: @Misunderstood All of the ones I had in mind.

Comment: https://m.ebay.com/itm/Sure-5-32V-Boost-Driver-for-10W-LED-DC-DC-Constant-Current-Power-Supply-Module-/161047962520  $1.83 in EBay http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=161047962520&category=181880&pm=1&ds=0&t=1521795955000&ver=0&cspheader=1